What constraints on a covariance matrix do conditional-independence assumptions lead to?
For $\rho\in (0,1)$ take Gaussian random variables $x_1 = \rho z + n_1, \ x_2 = \rho z + n_2$ with $n_1,n_2$ and $z$ iid normal with 0 mean and variance 1.
Take general random variables $(u_1,u_2)$ where

$u_1$ is independent of $(x_2,u_2)$ after conditioning on $x_1$
$u_2$ is independent of $(x_1,u_1)$ after conditioning on $x_2$
$(u_1,u_2)$ are independent of $z$ after conditioning on $(x_1,x_2)$

Can anything be said about the covariance matrix of $(z,x_1,x_2,\mathbb{E}[z,x_1,x_2|u_1,u_2])$?

If $(u_1,u_2)$ were each real random variables maybe one would be able to use precision matrices to translate the specification into a system of equations on the covariance's entries. In general I don't know.
Specializing to $(u_1,u_2,x_1,x_2, z)$ jointly-Gaussian I think at least $\mathrm{cov} (z,\mathbb{E}[z|u_1,u_2]) = \mathbb{E}[z|\mathbb{E}[x_1,x_2|u_1,u_2]]$ but what forms this can take I haven't worked out, and this is only one of the 27 specified entries. In general I don't know how to leverage the problem structure.

First, a stupid question for understanding your problem. Let $A,B,C $ three rv defined on the same probability space. What does it mean to say that $A$ is independent of B conditioned by $C? $ The Probebility space on which $A$ lives is not the same as the probability space on which $B|C$ lives. But may be you mean $A|C$ is independent of $B|C?$

I’m not sure what “B|C” is, sorry.
By “A is conditionally independent of B given C” I mean that A and B are independent given $\sigma(C)$. If $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ are the probability triple A,B,C live in then you can get a new measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ by conditioning on $\sigma(C)$, that is if $e\in\mathcal{F}$ then $\mu[e|\sigma(C)]=\mathbb{E}[1_e(\omega)|\sigma(C)].$ I mean that under this new measure A and B are independent.

OK. law $B|C $ means law of $B$ knowing $C$. You have answered my question: I correctely guessed.
